# Dynamic PDF and Accessible via ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, adobe, accessibility, acrobat

I have been doing dynamic PDF creation via ASP.net for some time -- in the form of HTML to PDF conversion.  It works well for us, but we have accessibility requirements from the State to make everything is accessible.  For static PDFs, we simply "tag" the files manually using Adobe's accessibility tools.  Of course this does not work for dynamically created files.  PDFs that I create dynamically fail the Acrobat Pro Accessibility test.

Does anyone have any ideas about create PDFs dynamically in ASP.net, but producing PDFs that are tagged and can pass the Adobe Accessiblity test?  I have researched many components, but none that I have found support tagging.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Aspose.Words and/or Aspose.Pdf for PDF generation?

Comment: To provide accessibility to form fields, you can set the formfield tooltip (known in the PDF Reference as **alternate name**). Our product, Gnostice PDFOne .NET allows you to <a href="http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=176&t=Generate_PDF_Forms_In_ASP_NET_Using_PDFOne_NET_v3">create dynamic PDF forms</a> and also set form field tooltips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look seriously at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). AFAIK, this is the definitive library for creating dynamic PDF's, for Java and .NET.

You will need the book [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/).

Here's a quote from iText in Action on accessibility:

"You can use iText to create a document that passes all the criteria that are listed in Section 508."

Comment: Thanks.  I think I had reviewed iText once before but did not see the sections on accessibility.  I will definitely go pick up a copy of that book.